# Modifing one off many post with JS and Django?

Tags: javascript, django

I am currently working on the CS50Web network project4 and I am stuck in editing a post among many posts that are displayed.

I have a view that displays all the posts done by a user.

```
def profile(request, username):
    if request.method == "GET":
        user = User.objects.filter(username=username)
        profile = Profile.objects.filter(user=user[0]).get()
        posts = Post.objects.filter(user=user[0]).order_by('-publish_date')
        return render(
            request,
            'network/profile.html',
            {
                'posts': page,
                'profile': profile,
            }
        )
```

And it is displayed in and html template.

```
{% for post in posts %}
<div class="card text-center">
    <div class="card-header">
        <a href="{% url 'profile' post.user %}"> {{ post.user }} </a>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">{{ post.content }}</h5>
      <p class="card-text">{{ post.num_likes }}</p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="editpost()"> Edit </a>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer text-muted">
        {{ post.publish_date }}
    </div>
</div>
<br>
{% endfor %}
```

I understand that I need to have a function that with JS changes the `<h5>` tag and `<p>` tag from within that specific form but I know how to get it from only that one post and not from all of the posts that are being produced by Djangos templating engine.

Once I can select them I will copy their information into a var and change the style so the display is non as well as create introduce  was I will introduce the data from the vars and allow the user to modify them.

Then will create a new `<a>` was for the user to save the changes. For now, I am thinking of using Ajax to send the data back to the server but I'm open to suggestion if there is a better.

I would upload the model for the database but I don't think it's necessary for this. Any help or direction is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JavaScript you use in your template gives clues as to how to access each post for the user (ie `for post in posts`) and to set the values that appear in the that post's `h5` element (ie `post.content`) and `p` element (ie `post.num_likes`).

To update all of these in the view, you would do something like:

```
posts = Post.objects.filter(user=user[0]).order_by('-publish_date');

for (let post in posts){
  post.content = my_new_content;
  post.num_likes = my_new_num_likes;
}

return render( // etc...
```

Or if you wanted to leave the underlying values as they are, and update only the DOM (template) values, you'd just change the template-updating code to:

```
  <h5 class="card-title">{{ my_new_content }}</h5>
  <p class="card-text">{{ my_new_num_likes }}</p>
```

---

I was confused by this part: "...change the style so the display is non as well as create introduce was I will introduce the data...", but if you're trying to access the DOM elements after they are rendered, there are several useful, related techniques [documented on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Manipulating_documents).

For your situation, if all the cards appear on the same page, you might do something like:

```
const
  // Defines an array to hold values found in the DOM
  oldCardInfoArray = [],

  // Collects references to all card elements on the page
  cards = document.getElementsByClassName("card"),

  // Converts cards to an array, and gets only those cards whose user matches `post.user`
  //   (Assumes this code has access to some `post` object with a `user` property)
  userCards = (Array.from(cards)).filter( 
    (card) => card.querySelector("a").textContent.trim() == post.user)
  );

// Loops through the userCards
for(let userCard of userCards){
  const
    // Identifies title and text of each card (as `oldTitle` and `oldText`, respectively) 
    cardTitleElement = userCard.querySelector(".card-title"),
    cardTextElement = userCard.querySelector(".card-text"),
    oldTitle = cardTitleElement.textContent,
    oldText = cardTextElement.textContent,

    // Makes an `oldCardInfo` object with two properties, and adds it to the array
    oldCardInfo = { oldTitle: oldTitle, oldText: oldText };
  oldCardInfoArray.push(oldCardInfo);
}

// Now the array is populated, and we can do something with its contents
for(let card of oldCardInfoArray){
  const oldTitle = card.oldTitle;
  const oldText = card.oldText;
  // Prints the values from each card to the browser console
  //   (or you could send them to the server, or whatever)
  console.log("title: " + oldTitle + ", text: " + oldText);
}
```

Obviously, all this code is untested, but it should at least give you some ideas.

---

**EDIT:**
In response to your comment, **to select the card** that contains the clicked button, you could just put code like this in your `editPost` function:

```
const card = this.closest(".card");
```

So now, instead of looping through the cards, you'll be able to work with only those elements within the card that the user interacted with (which happens just like with `cardTitleElement`, above).

**Or, alternatively**, you could replace your inline event handler (`onclick = editPost()` in the template) with an [event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#examples), either 1) inside a `<script>` element at the bottom of your template or 2) directly in your existing JavaScript code (although I'm not sure which part of Django handles this second approach).  It might look something like:

```
document.addEventListener("click", editPost);

function editPost(event){ // Listener sees triggering event
  const clickedThing = event.target; // Event has useful properties
  const userCard = clickedThing.closest(".card");
  if(userCard){ // Makes sure button has a `card` ancestor before proceeding

    // Now, with the correct card identified, we can collect values from it
    const cardTitleElement = userCard.querySelector(".card-title");
    const cardTextElement = userCard.querySelector(".card-text");
      // ...etc, as described above
  }
}
```

Comment: So I see what you are saying but I don't understand how it knows which post I have selected. It displays 10 post per page. Its not a question of machine post with users its a question of knowing which post the user has chosen to edit among a list of 10 which where created by Djangos templating engine. How do I get my code to extract the info from the form where the Botton was pressed?